Atiyah-MacDonald Ex. 5.10
I have already proven Ex. 5.10 of Atiyah-MacDonald.
The exercise uses the setup of a ring homomorphism $f: A \to B$ with $f^* : Spec(B) \to Spec(A)$ and asks to prove that:
"Let q be any prime ideal of $B$ and $p = q^c$. Then $f^* : Spec(B/q) \to Spec(A/p)$ is surjective" $\iff$ $f$ satisfies the conclusion of the "going-up property" listed in Thm 5.11, i.e. that given any sequence of primes $p_1 \subseteq p_2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq p_n$ in $f(A)$ and $q_1 \subseteq q_2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq q_m$ in $B$ (m<n) such that $q_i \cap f(A) = p_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq m$), the chain in $B$ can be extended to $q_n$ satisfying the same intersection property.
My proof uses the fact some pair $p_m, q_m$ exist already (given that it's stated $m \geq 1$). I pull the $p_m$ back to $A$ then mod out and surjectivity makes this trivial.
But, I'd like to make this iff statement stronger by only assuming the existence of some $p$ in $f(A)$ with no corresponding prime in $B$ to start with. Is that possible?
In other words, I'd like to use Ex. 5.10 i) (c) to prove the conclusion of Thm. 5.10.

That's why you're given the pair $p$ and $q$ in the statement of the problem, right?

Yes. The problem gives at least some $p_1, q_1$. But, I want to prove something stronger. I'm asking if we can still prove this assuming we are not given any $q$. (If you have access to the book), I'm basically trying to prove the conclusion of Thm. 5.10 given the $f*$ surjective property from Ex. 5.10 i) (c).

Oh, I see. Maybe you could edit your post to make it more clear what precisely you're asking?

Edited. thanks.

The simplest counter-example I can think off to your problem is the following:
Consider a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ which is not contained in all prime ideals of $I$ (since it is a counterexample, you can start with such a pair, say $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $I = \langle x \rangle$). Let $A = R$ and $B = R/I$. For any prime $p \in spec(B)$ and $q = p^c$, we infact have from isomorphism theorems,  $f~ mod~ q : A/q \rightarrow B/p$ is  an isomorphism and hence $f^*$ is infact bijective. But $A$ has prime ideals by assumption which do not contain $I$ and hence are not contractions of prime ideals in $B$, so you cannot arrive at the conclusion of Thm 5.10.

That makes perfect sense, thanks.
